# Scaling problem when visualizing cryptocoin data

Tags: visualization, cryptocurrency, timeserieschart

I am trying to visualize cryptocoin data with predicted values of it in the future.I used open and close values of coin to make candle charts.When I add predicted values because of the difference  between predicted value and already occured values.Matplotlib automatically scales it and candle chart gets really small.

[An Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrPmN.png)

I tried to apply standard scaling but I the close price of coin is really close and standard deviation gets low as a result which makes any value greater than 1-2 % couple std away from mean.

Comment: Use a secondary Y-axis for the predicted values. This way, the candlestick chart will be on the primary Y-axis, and the predictions won't affect its scale.